# Is there a way to block "windows" tags?

Tags: support, ignored-tags

Right now on serverfault I'm ignoring windows stuff, because I'm not a windows guy. The problem is that "all" windows tags have duplicates.

Examples:
windowsserver2003, windows-server-2003, windows2003 (and the same for 2008),
sqlserver, sqlserver2005, mssql, ms-office ms-office-2007, visualstudio, visual-studio, windowsxp, windows-xp, etc..., etc..

Or should I request that these tags be merged? I hereby do so.

Comment: Maybe allow for some tag grouping instead. Create a "Windows development" group on SO that would include stuff like: winforms, windows*, win32, winapi, sqlserver*, etc.

I have the exact same problem. My 'ignored tags' are exceeding half of the page. Tag groups could also be beneficial in favorite tags, where I'm insterested in mostly anything open source. Just an idea.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use wildcards in your ignore.

So if you put in `*windows*` it will ignore any tags containing "windows" at any point inside.

And here's a link to the blog article: [Interesting and Ignored Tags Now Support Wildcards](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/interesting-and-ignored-tags-now-support-wildcards/)

Comment: Nice tip there Paolo :)

Answer (score 0):

You can at least use wildcards, see [here](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/interesting-and-ignored-tags-now-support-wildcards/). This does make it easier for you some if you enter *windows*, *sqlserver*, ...

It would make sense to merge some of the tags (like windows7 and windows-7), but then other are used to distinguish version specific problems and questions.